# Como carregar uma view dentro de um layout?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, layout

Estou tentando carregar uma *view* dentro de um *layout*, segue meu *controller* abaixo:

```php
class IndexController extends BaseController {
    protected $layout = 'admin.layouts.default';

    public function index()
    {
        $this->layout->$this->layoutcontent =  View::make('admin.index');
    }
}
```

Porém está retornando o seguinte erro:

> Attempt to assign property of non-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para incluir sub-views dentro do layout, pode ser desta forma:

```
@include('view.name')
```

Passando valores:

```
@include('view.name', array('some'=>'data'))
```

Answer (score 4):

O Erro está neste trecho:

```php
$this->layout->$this->layoutcontent =  View::make('admin.index');
```

A propriedade é `content` mas tu tens `$this->layoutcontent`, deverás alterar para :

```php
$this->layout->content = View::make('admin.index');
```

Ver também a documentação em: [Laravel - Controller Layouts](http://laravel.com/docs/templates#controller-layouts) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>